# Go to View Controller after Login Success Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, authentication

How would I direct a user to a defined View Controller when a success from a URL request is done. I have a Login page with a username and password field. Below is my code. Any assistance
would be greatly appreciated.

```
#import "LoginTableViewController.h"

@interface LoginTableViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *UIEmailTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *UIPasswordTextField;

@end

@implementation LoginTableViewController
@synthesize UIEmailTextField;
@synthesize UIPasswordTextField;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setUIEmailTextField:nil];
[self setUIPasswordTextField:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - barButton Outlet

- (IBAction)loginButtonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
NSString *data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",UIEmailTextField.text, UIPasswordTextField.text];
NSData *postData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

// preaparing URL request to send data.

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.twitter.com"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setTimeoutInterval:7.0];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;

NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Login response:%@",str);

NSLog(@"Log In button was pressed!");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it set up now, your NSURLConnection will block the main thread until it finishes.  If you use an asynchronous NSURLConnection, you can become it's delegate and respond appropriately to failures and successes like so:

```
NSURLConnection* connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];  //Conform to NSURLConnectionDelegate before you use this.

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response
{
    //Got a response.  Not necessarily an error, so login might have been successful,
    //or it might not have.
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
    //The connection returned data.  Really only useful for requesting files.
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    //Handle the error properly
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection
{
    //Connection's finished completely.  Probably a good time to check for an error,
    //Or change the view controller 
}
```

*Also, more of a sidenote, properties should ***NOT*** begin with capital letters in ObjC, that's the case that classes use.  And it's always wise not to dip into the UI- namespace for variable names.*

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do a login page, I'd suggest a different approach:  Put up the page that a successful login will take you to first, and make it your root view controller.  Then, immediately, push the login controller as a modal controller.  This way, even if the login fails, you can push the login screen back up again.  This also clears up your code if you allow the user to retain his credentials and not have to log in again after startup (if that's applicable).  Anyway, it's a cleaner approach.  You don't have the login screen back at the rootViewController level.

Answer (score 0):

Setup your view controllers so that dismissing the `LoginTableViewController` will show the appropriate view controller after successful login.

For example:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;

    LoginTableViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginTableViewController alloc] init];
    [rootViewController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:NO completion:nil];

    return YES;
}
```

When the login is successful, dismiss the `LoginTableViewController`:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```